# How to resolve css incompabilities/differences between different versions of IE?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, stylesheet

I am having an issue wherein my web application behaves different in `(IE5 & IE6)` as compared with `(IE7 & IE8)`

There is some `CSS` Issue but I do not want to get in a situation where I make some changes in `CSS File` and web application would work fine in `(IE5 & IE6)` and not in `(IE7 & IE8)` and so my question is:

`How should I approach problem to resolve CSS incompatibities or differences between different version of IE ?`

Any guidance and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what your question exactly is about. What do you mean by "approach" - where to put the CSS rules for the various browsers?

Comment: @Pekka: How can I make sure that my application appears same in all different versions of IE ?, currently application appears fine in IE7 and IE8 but not in IE5 and IE6, hope this helps.

Comment: @Rachel this is a huge issue, there is no single answer for this. Just fix the problems step by step. Almost every cross-browser problem has been discussed here on SO. But why do you still need to fix things for *IE5*? That browser is deader than dead, and IE 6 will hopefully follow soon.

Comment: @Pekka: Client for our Application is somehow using IE5 and IE6, as off now we do not have any reason to block older versions of IE and so are facing this issue.

Comment: @Rachel Depending on the complexity of your application, fixing CSS for IE6 will be cumbersome enough, but for IE5 it's going to be a *nightmare*. There is **no** reason for anybody to use IE5 in 2010. It's even highly dangerous, as there are no security fixes for that browser any more.

Comment: @Pekka: Is there a way other than what suggested in answers to make changes in css file for IE6 which would not affect IE7 and IE8  ?

Comment: @Rachel using conditional comments and separate style sheets is in fact the easiest way. (Having one style sheet per browser version, containing the rules exclusive to that browser)

Comment: hmm...ok...probably I will guess with that approach only...thanks for all the info...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cascade of style sheets like so:

```
<link id="stylesheet1" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" /
<!--[if IE]>
  <link id="stylesheet2" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
  <link id="stylesheet3" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie6.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 5]>
  <link id="stylesheet4" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie5.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

style.css:

```
.myclass{
  width:100px;
}
```

ie.css:

```
/* override class from style.css */
.myclass{
  width:105px;
}
```

ie6.css:

```
/* override class again from ie.css */
.myclass{
  width:110px;
}
```

ie5.css:

```
/* if necessary, override class again from ie6.css */
.myclass{
  width:115px;
}
```

You only need to over-ride what needs to be over-ridden.

Pekka is right, you need to take each problem/bug/display-difference on a case-by-case basis.  So if something isn't showing up right in IE6, you need to adjust it in `ie6.css`.  If even after that, it's not showing up right in IE5, you need to adjust it in `ie5.css`.

If you practice a little, you will understand better.

---

Explanation:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  only Internet Explorer browsers (all versions) will see HTML between these statements
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
  only Internet Explorer 6 or lower browsers will see HTML between these statements
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 5]>
  only Internet Explorer 5 or lower browsers will see HTML between these statements
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: hmm...so for each IE version, I just have to over-ride what ever modification I need form css point of view and there is no other way to do so.

Comment: Ok. I will go with this approach only.

Comment: Not the only way, you can use `<!--[if lte IE 6]>` to dynamically modify the HTML for each browser too, but **over-riding the CSS selectors is the best way to handle these problems IMO**.  That is what the "Cascade" in "Cascading Style Sheets" was intended for.

Comment: Is this way, how we recognize which browser version it is, am new to this and so not sure as to how can we recognize the browser version ?

Comment: Does my further "explanation" answer that question?

Comment: @JohnB-Yes, it did answer my question. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @JohnB-One thing, how did you get that line before giving explanation ?

Comment: @Rachel: 3rd button from the right in the WYSIWYG editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html). Put IE version specific css in specific files only included for the particular version in question.